# In PyObjC how do you get a sheet to end after using runModalForWindow_?

Tags: python, cocoa, pyobjc

I have a secondary window (a sheet) for a dialog controlled by a secondard WindowController. For some reason, the actions never get called in NSObject subclass after the sheet is displayed. I have confirmed and re-linked the actions. The code runs to runModalForWindow_ but then never receives the ok or cancel actions. So the sheet never goes away. What am I missing here? I cant seem to find any pyobjc examples on thier website that does a runModalForWindow_...

```
    @objc.IBAction
def okSelected(self, sender):
    self.dialogResult = objc.YES
    NSLog("OK")
    #NSApp.endSheet_(self.newTurnWindowOutlet)
    NSApp.stopModalWithCode_(objc.OK)

@objc.IBAction
def cancelSelected(self, sender):
    self.dialogResult = objc.NO
    #NSApp.endSheet_(self.newTurnWindowOutlet)
    NSApp.stopModalWithCode_(objc.NO)

def runSheet(self, parent):
    NSApp.beginSheet_modalForWindow_modalDelegate_didEndSelector_contextInfo_(
        self.newTurnWindowOutlet, parent, None, 
        self.sheetDidEnd_returnCode_contextInfo_, None)
    NSLog("runModelForWindow")
    result = NSApp.runModalForWindow_(self.newTurnWindowOutlet)
    NSLog(str(result))
    NSApp.endSheet_(self.newTurnWindowOutlet)
    self.newTurnWindowOutlet.orderOut_(self)
    return self.dialogResult
```

Comment: full xcode project source is located at:
http://battle.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/battle/Skirmish/trunk/MacSkirmish/

Comment: Specifically:
http://battle.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/battle/Skirmish/trunk/MacSkirmish/NewTurnController.py?revision=185&view=markup

Comment: looking deeper into the console messages i see:
 Could not connect the action cancelSelected: to target of class NewTurnController

What does this mean? I disconnected, saved, and re-connected the action. Still this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines

```
    @objc.IBAction
    def okSelected(self, sender):
```

should be

```
    @objc.IBAction
    def okSelected_(self, sender):
```

etc. Remember, every colon in an Objective-C selector becomes an _ in Python!

Comment: THats it! I keep forgetting that principal. THanks